# Magento 2 Disable FPC for single CMS page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, cms-pages

I have seen that there is a option available to disable FPC for single CMS page in **Magento 1**.
Is there anything available to do it in **Magento 2**?

Comment: Can you describe use case?

Comment: @KAndy I have restricted access for one CMS page that is available only for special Customer groups. When FPC cache is turned off it works perfectly. Turned on first time my restriction is working, but on second time FPC bypasses and shows the page for non logged in customers.

Comment: Are you calling your own block or is it just a  regular html block in admin